Interface disappears when setting static IP on clean install
I'm at a loss on this one. On a hyper-v VM I've done a clean fresh install of 24.04 and ran apt-get update and upgrade. After setting the IP address within the GUI settings menu the interface disappears and is no longer configurable from the GUI. The only work around I've found is to modify /usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf and add except:type:ethernet. This brings the interface back up and allows network traffic but I can't modify the settings and NetworkManager crashes repeatedly.
Any thoughts on this would be greatly appriciated.
